# How can i create application look like yahoo messenger on desktop?

Tags: java

How can i create application look like yahoo messenger on desktop?

i need some suggest and tutorials, i think it use database + socket technology.

Everybody can give me some suggest!

Thank you

Comment: you can use java to program that. However if u just want to play with friends and get password . there are already ready-made yahoo like tools available to get passwords. :)

Comment: @Mirage i need create application look like yahoo, but diffirent user interfaces , it mean chat application, but i wonder choose between RMI or Socket because it need multi thread for clients can chat to other person or groups,and send file or share album ... And i need help some tutorial about its :D

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to go with [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html), less to code and less low level programming than socket programming.

For database, to be simple, you can just do with [mysql](http://www.mysql.com/) or [javadb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) (javadb only if you just want to practice, nobody uses it in production)

Comment: Thankyou vodkhang, vietnamese programer :D i will try RMI with multithread :D

Comment: I don't get why somebody vote me down, uhmm, any reason will be appreciated

Comment: @MYE: so, you are also vnese?